# Null reference on Cache class issue

Tags: c#, caching, nullreferenceexception

I have code as following inside of method:

```
var currency = new Dictionary<string, List<Currency>>();

if (Cache["Currency"] == null)
{
    //here I fill currency with data and then set it to Cache.
    Cache["Currency"] = currency ;
}
else
{
     var currency = Cache["Currency"] as Dictionary<string, List<Currency>>;
     //here I am getting null reference exception:
     foreach (var item in currency)
}
```

I have read that Cache class should not be used directly from my application,
but what is the proper use of Cache class in my case?

EDIT:
I am posting all my code:

```
 protected void DisplayCurrency()
{
    Dictionary<string, List<Currency>> currList = new Dictionary<string, List<Currency>>();

    if (Cache["Currency"] == null)
    {
        var xmlDoc = XElement.Load("http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml");
        if (xmlDoc != null)
        {
            var queryXML = from xml in xmlDoc.Elements("Currency")
                           where (string)xml.Attribute("Kod") == "USD" || (string)xml.Attribute("Kod") == "EUR"
                           select xml;

            if (queryXML != null)
            {
                //fill Dictionary with data
                foreach (var item in queryXML)
                {
                    currList.Add(item.Attribute("Kod").Value, new List<Currency> 
                        {
                             new Currency 
                                 {     
                                     ForexBuying    = item.Element("ForexBuying").Value,
                                     ForexSelling   = item.Element("ForexSelling").Value, 
                                     BanknoteBuying = item.Element("BanknoteBuying").Value,
                                     BanknoteSelling= item.Element("BanknoteSelling").Value
                                 }
                        });
                }
                //Cache["Currency"] = currList;
                HttpContext.Current.Cache["Currency"] = currList;

                //read data from Dictionary instance
                foreach (var item in currList)
                {
                    switch (item.Key)
                    {
                        case "USD":
                            litUSDtxt.Text = item.Key;
                            foreach (var i in item.Value)
                            {
                                litUSD.Text = i.BanknoteSelling;
                            }
                            break;

                        case "EUR":
                            litEURtxt.Text = item.Key;
                            foreach (var i in item.Value)
                            {
                                litEUR.Text = i.BanknoteSelling;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Cache.Insert("Currency", currList, null, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), TimeSpan.Zero);
    }
    else
    {
        var currency = Cache["Currency"] as Dictionary<string, List<Currency>>;
        foreach (var item in currency)
        {
            switch (item.Key)
            {
                case "USD":
                    litUSDtxt.Text = item.Key;
                    foreach (var i in item.Value)
                    {
                        litUSD.Text = i.BanknoteSelling;
                    }
                    break;

                case "EUR":
                    litEURtxt.Text = item.Key;
                    foreach (var i in item.Value)
                    {
                        litEUR.Text = i.BanknoteSelling;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}


class Currency
{
    public string ForexBuying { get; set; }
    public string ForexSelling { get; set; }
    public string BanknoteBuying { get; set; }
    public string BanknoteSelling { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: did you refer this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: what are you storing in `Cache["Currency"] = someObject` line. i.e someobject is of what type

Comment: seems that the object in `Cache["Currency"]` isn't of type `Dictionary<string, List<Currency>>`

Comment: When you set the cache item, is 'someObject' a Dictionary<string, List<Currency>> ?

Comment: @RajeevKumar. I am setting 'Dictionary<string, List<Currency>> currency = new Dictionary<string, List<Currency>>();' like 'Cache["Currency"]=currency;'

Comment: Ok so, did you add any item in  `currList ` before assigning it to `Cache["Currency"]`

Comment: @RajeevKumar. Yes, I did, and it works. The problem is in else clause.

Comment: try to debug else part and check if it is casting problem or Cache["Currency"] is itself null

Comment: Other thing to note you needn't to cast here as you storing value in var type.

Comment: @black123 are you here ?? Any progress ...

Comment: @RajeevKumar. I had problems with connection. Now I am back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First a few points:

1. Do NOT initialize `currency` every time. That is a waste of time, when the cache already contains an instance.
2. Never try to check if something in the cache and than retrieve it in two different steps. Between those steps, the cache could have been clear by anohter process, creating a `NullReferenceException`.
3. In your first edit of your question, you put some other object inside the cache. Check your software at other location. If ANYWHERE in your code `Cache["Currency"]` is filled with an object of anohter type, the `as` operation will always return `null`.

Your code must look like this:

```
var currency = Cache["Currency"] as Dictionary<string, List<Currency>>;
if (currency == null)
{
    currency = new Dictionary<string, List<Currency>>();
    // At this point, initialize currency, fill it with data from your XML file, or whatever.
    Cache["Currency"] = currency;
}
// At this point, currency is loaded from cache or recreated. Now you can use it to fill your controls, variables, etc.
```

Or... to revice your whole code:

```
protected void DisplayCurrency()
{
    var currency = Cache["Currency"] as Dictionary<string, List<Currency>>;

    if (currency == null)
    {
        currency = new Dictionary<string,List<Currency>>();
        var xmlDoc = XElement.Load("http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml");
        if (xmlDoc != null)
        {
            var queryXML = from xml in xmlDoc.Elements("Currency")
                           where (string)xml.Attribute("Kod") == "USD" || (string)xml.Attribute("Kod") == "EUR"
                           select xml;

            if (queryXML != null)
            {
                //fill Dictionary with data
                foreach (var item in queryXML)
                {
                    currency.Add(item.Attribute("Kod").Value, new List<Currency> 
                    {
                         new Currency 
                         {     
                             ForexBuying    = item.Element("ForexBuying").Value,
                             ForexSelling   = item.Element("ForexSelling").Value, 
                             BanknoteBuying = item.Element("BanknoteBuying").Value,
                             BanknoteSelling= item.Element("BanknoteSelling").Value
                         }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        Cache["Currency"] = currency;
    }
    foreach (var item in currency)
    {
        switch (item.Key)
        {
            case "USD":
                litUSDtxt.Text = item.Key;
                foreach (var i in item.Value)
                {
                    litUSD.Text = i.BanknoteSelling;
                }
                break;

            case "EUR":
                litEURtxt.Text = item.Key;
                foreach (var i in item.Value)
                {
                    litEUR.Text = i.BanknoteSelling;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RajeevKumar Might not, but it's just the right way to do it in general.

Comment: @Rajeev: Well.. OP states in his title he has a Null Reference Issue. This will solve that issue.

Comment: @MartinMulder i agree it will solve that problem. But the hidden issue is that why null ??

Comment: @MartinMulder. I am posting my complete code. It will be easier to understant

Comment: @Rajeev: Please read my second point in my text. That could be the couse.

Comment: @MartinMulder that may be the issue. You have point out good reasons for the cause of issue. Only OP has to check and tell if it really solve it for him/her

Comment: @MartinMulder. By 2. did you mean that I should not use else clause or what?

Comment: @Black123: No. I mean that you not first check (`Cache["Currency"] == null`) and that retrieve (`var currency = Cache["Currency"]...`) because between those steps, the cache could have been cleared.

Comment: @MartinMulder. Thank you. That was very educational explanation

Comment: @Black123: You are very welcome! I added some extra code that might help you. It is shorter that your own (if I see duplicate code, I always want to eliminate that).

Comment: @MartinMulder. Well, I was just about thinking to remove duplicate code :) Thank you very much. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var currency = Cache["Currency"] as Dictionary<string, List<Currency>>;
```

Clearly the cast has failed and `currency` is null (This is correct behavior if the conversion isn't possible).  You need to check if it is `null`:

```
if (currency != null) {
    foreach(var item in currency) {

    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you're setting it up to the wrong variable, shouldn't it be:

```
Cache["Currency"] = currency;
```

instead of:

```
Cache["Currency"] = someObject;
```

Or in case you really mean to use `someObject` make sure it's of type `Dictionary<string, List<Currency>>` otherwise `as` will return `null`.

**EDIT**

Make sure you're using `HttpContext.Cache`, this is a common issue:

```
HttpContext.Cache["Currency"] = currency;
```

Comment: I set it to currency. There is no mistake

Comment: @black123 in your example it says `someObject`, you have to make sure `someObject` is the same type as the one you're casting to otherwise you'd get `null`

Comment: Correct, that's my mistake in code posting. It is set to currency.

Comment: I stil have the same problem. If you want I can post all my code?

Comment: @black123 did you getting Cache["Currency"] itself null or var Currency null in else part ?

Comment: @RajeevKumar. I am getting null in else part

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to debug else part with following code

```
else
{
  currrency = Cache["Currency"] ;
 //here I am getting null reference exception:
 foreach (var item in currency)
}
```

Comment: let me know if you are still getting var curr null

Comment: Did you try run this code. I just wanna know if it is not a casting problem in your code

Comment: If I use it that way I can not iterate over data. Look at my complete code. Thank you

Comment: Well, I am using foreach loop.